# Is it true to say that as of 2020, chemists can create any gemstone, from 1 to 10 level of Mohs' Scale strengths, artificially?

Tags: minerals

Please, I have a question here as a non chemist:

Is it true to say that as of 2020, chemists can create any gemstone, from 1 to 10 level of Mohs' Scale strengths, artificially?

If so, please detail if it causes any serious financial damages to the "old school" gemstone industry of picking and mining and polishing gemstones from natural environments and deposits respectively, or if the two industries keep thriving one alongside the other.

Comment: All the exemplars in the hardness scale are minerals, but all minerals are not gemstones.

Comment: "Gemstones" each have a characteristic fundamental "shape", you cannot force them to grow into another one.

Comment: Defining “gemstone” is a bit tricky. Roughly speaking, a gemstone is a mineral specimen, natural or synthetic, that has been fashioned by a gem cutter. There is no requirement that a finished gemstone be flawless, have a naturally occurring crystal habit, be hard on the Moh’s scale, be chemically resistant, have no easy cleavage(s), be rare as a mineral, and so on. This question could get a really long and detailed answer.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the original Mohs scale is qualitative, arguably we can also make a select few materials "above 10", in the sense that they would scratch diamond without themselves being scratched by diamond. One that comes to mind right now is [aggregated diamond nanorods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregated_diamond_nanorod).

Comment: @Karl if it's okay I ask; why for example should it be different than growing a watermelon in a box to get a quadrangular shape?

Comment: Confine each growing crystal in a box? Well, that might work, if your box can stand the conditions, and you can suppress more crystals to grow *from* the walls. Chances are that touching the wall induces all kinds of growth defects. And it sounds a bit impractical to me.